# Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Table name in Databse is: empCode

Spring boot table mapping :

```
@Column(name="empCode")
    String empCode;
```

getting error this:

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'emp_code'.

RestController:

```
@GetMapping("/employee")
    public List<Employee> findAll() {
        return employeeService.findAll();
    }
```

I didn't define this emp_code anywhere, please assist why?

I changed the name in table from empCode to empCODE then it is working but in my office project I am facing same error but there I can't change column name because other organisation also using same database.

Comment: See https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-naming-strategy

Answer (score 1):

Surround your column name with backticks:

```
@Column(name = "`empCode`")
```

This way hibernate will use the specific name instead of renaming it according to its own convention

Comment: Not working still facing the same error.

Comment: And when you use `@Column(name = "\"empCode\"")` ?